# masstransit with rabbitmq: Why message auto moved to ***_skipped queue when it responing

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

**UCITY.API request to UCITY.USER's "ucity_us_mobilephonecomplete" queue and receive message but Masstransit auto move it to the skip queue**

but other queues are working successfully

**Masstransit Trace Log：**

```
2018-03-23 15:59:22.5727|DEBUG|MassTransit.Messages|SEND rabbitmq://192.168.1.142/us/ucity_us_mobilephonecomplete 0b350000-dafb-1866-5b48-08d59093fd36 MQNamespace.USER.IMobilephoneCompleteRequest

2018-03-23 15:59:22.6077|DEBUG|MassTransit.Messages|SKIP rabbitmq://192.168.1.142/us/bus-WIN-VH8418VRIC5-UCITY.API-bc4oyyg49ccgcqg6bdk3br7trf?durable=false&autodelete=true N/A
```

**Message Detail**

he server reported 1 messages remaining.

```
Exchange    bus-WIN-VH8418VRIC5-UCITY.API-bc4oyyg49ccgcqg6bdk3br7trf_skipped
Routing Key 
Redelivered ●
Properties  
message_id: 0b350000-dafb-1866-d0af-08d59093bae2
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
Content-Type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
publishId:  1
MT-Reason:  dead-letter
MT-Host-MachineName:    WIN-VH8418VRIC5
MT-Host-ProcessName:    UCITY.API
MT-Host-ProcessId:  14648
MT-Host-Assembly:   UCITY.API
MT-Host-AssemblyVersion:    1.0.0.0
MT-Host-MassTransitVersion: 4.0.1.1390
MT-Host-FrameworkVersion:   4.0.30319.42000
MT-Host-OperatingSystemVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
content_type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
Payload
1060 bytes
Encoding: string
{

    "messageId": "0b350000-dafb-1866-d0af-08d59093bae2",

    "requestId": "0b350000-dafb-1866-8267-08d59093bade",

    "conversationId": "0b350000-dafb-1866-0ddf-08d59093bae2",

    "sourceAddress": "rabbitmq://192.168.1.142/us/ucity_us_mobilephonecomplete",

    "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://192.168.1.142/us/bus-WIN-VH8418VRIC5-UCITY.API-bc4oyyg49ccgcqg6bdk3br7trf?durable=false&autodelete=true",

    "messageType": [

        "urn:message:MQNamespace:IBaseResponseModel"

    ],

    "message": {

        "code": 4212,

        "correlationId": "73989f86-51fd-4ae1-a467-a556a165f125",

        "message": "COMPLETEMOBILEPHONE FAILD!USERWECHAT MOBILEPHONE COMPLETED",

        "timeStamp": "2018-03-23T15:57:31.3218406+08:00"

    },

    "headers": {},

    "host": {

        "machineName": "WIN-VH8418VRIC5",

        "processName": "UCITY.USER",

        "processId": 8952,

        "assembly": "UCITY.USER",

        "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",

        "frameworkVersion": "4.0.30319.42000",

        "massTransitVersion": "4.0.1.1390",

        "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"
    }
}
```

the skipped queue what does it do 
thanks for answer

Comment: Do you have the request client waiting for the response from the service? Without code it's hard to figure out why the message is skipped.

Comment: I have uploaded my code.I am waiting for your reply Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the response is of the baseResponseModel message type, and the actual type isn't being returned. Get rid of the temporary variable and just sent the proper response type.

Comment: You can't use `"urn:message:MQNamespace:IBaseResponseModel"` as the only message type, either use object to response (so it discovers all the types) or use the actual response type that your request client expects.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this method to use the proper response type, instead of the base interface.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest> context)
{
    var dispatch = new UserDispatch(context.Message.CorrelationId);
    try
    {
        var response = await dispatch.MobilephoneComplete(context.Message);
        return context.RespondAsync(response);
    }
    catch (UCException ucEx)
    {
        var response = new AuthenticationResponse(context.Message.CorrelationId)
        {
            Code = ucEx.Code,
            Message = ucEx.Message
        };
        return context.RespondAsync(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var response = new AuthenticationResponse(context.Message.CorrelationId)
        {
            Code = (int)EnumErrorStatus.UserError,
            Message = ex.Message
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
        return context.RespondAsync(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me also. The day after I figured out the problem, the cause seems to be using the Autofac register method for the current assembly like:

```
builder.RegisterConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Using the following (**explicit registration for each consumer**) instead was solved the binding problem:

```
builder.RegisterType<YouConsumerHandler>();
```

Answer (score -1):

UCIT.API code

```
//execute request
public async Task<ResultOpenUserLogin> MobilephoneComplete(AuthenticationIdentity authenticationIdentity, ArguUserMobilephoneComplete arguUserMobilephoneComplete)
    {
        var response = await UserMobilephoneCompleteRequest.Client.Request(new UserMobilephoneCompleteRequest(CorrelationId)
        {
            DeviceType = authenticationIdentity.DeviceType,
            IdUser = authenticationIdentity.IdUser,
            Mobilephone = arguUserMobilephoneComplete.Mobilephone,
            Passcode = arguUserMobilephoneComplete.Passcode
        });// the request timeout
        if (response.Code != 200)
        {
            throw new UCException(response.Code, response.Message);
        }
        return new ResultOpenUserLogin()
        {
            Token = response.Token,
            UserInfoCompleted = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Mobilephone)
        };
    }


//UserMobilephoneCompleteRequest class detail
[RabbitMqUri(VirtualHost = "ucity_us", Queue = "ucity_us_mobilephonecomplete")]
public class UserMobilephoneCompleteRequest : BaseRequest, IMobilephoneCompleteRequest
{
    public UserMobilephoneCompleteRequest(Guid? correlationId) : base(correlationId)
    {

    }
    public int DeviceType { get; set; }

    public int IdUser { get; set; }

    public string Mobilephone { get; set; }

    public string Passcode { get; set; }

    public static IRequestClient<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest, IAuthenticationResponse> Client
    {
        get
        {
            return _requestClient;
        }
    }

    private static IRequestClient<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest, IAuthenticationResponse> _requestClient
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override void CreateClient(IBusControl busControl, Uri address)
    {
        _requestClient = busControl.CreateRequestClient<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest, IAuthenticationResponse>(address, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
}
```

UCIT.USER code

```
//these codes work well
 [RabbitMqUri(VirtualHost = "ucity_us", Queue = "ucity_us_mobilephonecomplete")]
public class MobilephoneCompleteConsumer : BaseConsumer<MobilephoneCompleteConsumer>, IConsumer<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMobilephoneCompleteRequest> context)
    {
        var dispatch = new UserDispatch(context.Message.CorrelationId);
        IBaseResponseModel response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await dispatch.MobilephoneComplete(context.Message);
        }
        catch (UCException ucEx)
        {
            response = new AuthenticationResponse(context.Message.CorrelationId)
            {
                Code = ucEx.Code,
                Message = ucEx.Message
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = new AuthenticationResponse(context.Message.CorrelationId)
            {
                Code = (int)EnumErrorStatus.UserError,
                Message = ex.Message
            };
            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
        }
        await context.RespondAsync(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from some explanation. Currently, it's basically a wall of code.